# Is there a way to get the user ID whose Thread was created on his message? discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to get user ID whose Thread channel is created on his message in the parent channel,
Idk if there is a way for it or not

it's not `channel.ownerId` This is for member who created thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`.fetchStarterMessage(options)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ThreadChannel?scrollTo=fetchStarterMessage) fetches the message that started the thread.

Comment: ```const StarterMessage = await interaction.channel.fetchStarterMessage();```

`${StarterMessage.member.id}`

thanks for help